# Python regex lookahead assertion

Tags: python, regex

I want to get word1 and word2 from text string like `text = "otherstuff word1 + word2"`.

I managed to get one word using this lookbehind regular expression:

```
r1 = re.search(r'(?<=\+\s)\w+', text) # Get word2
```

But whenever I try to do the same with the lookahead, regex it doesn't return anything

```
r2 = re.search(r'(?=(\s\+))\w+', text) # Get None
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: This pattern `(?=(\s\+))\w+` asserts what is directly to the right from the current position should be a whitespace char, but then you start the match with a word char which will not match.

Comment: You can get both words using a single pattern and 2 capturing groups `(\w+)\s\+\s(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/Ab94gT/1 or the other way around `(?<=\+\s)\w+|\w+(?=\s\+)` https://regex101.com/r/FRk5Hs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? Just swapped position of your `\w+` and `(?=(\s\+))`.

```
r2 = re.search(r'\w+(?=(\s\+))', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What did I do wrong ?

This pattern `(?=(\s\+))\w+` asserts what is directly to the right from the current position should be a whitespace char `\s` but then you start the match with a word char `\w` which will not match.

You could get both words by using a single pattern with an alternation `|` and switch the order of the lookaround.

```
(?<=\+\s)\w+|\w+(?=\s\+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FRk5Hs/1)

---

To get both words, you could also use 2 capturing groups instead of lookarounds:

```
(\w+)\s\+\s(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ab94gT/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w+)\s\+\s(\w+)"
s = "otherstuff word1 + word2."
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('word1', 'word2')]
```